# Find newest file in directory, then select all files with same DateTime

Tags: powershell

With this command, I can search for the newest file in a directory:

```
gci C:\temp | sort LastWriteTime -descending | select -first 1
```

My directory is rather large, containing 60'000+ txt files. Running this command takes:

```
PS C:\xy> measure-command {gci C:\temp | sort LastWriteTime -descending | select -first 1}


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 13
Milliseconds      : 465
Ticks             : 134657703
TotalDays         : 0.000155853822916667
TotalHours        : 0.00374049175
TotalMinutes      : 0.224429505
TotalSeconds      : 13.4657703
TotalMilliseconds : 13465.7703
```

As you can see, this command takes a long time to finish.

My task is to get all the files which have the same `LastWriteTime` Property as the file which the command returns (to the minute).

I tried something like this:

```
$file = gci C:\temp -OutVariable files | sort LastWriteTime -descending | 
        select -first 1 | % { $_.LastWriteTime }
$myfiles = $files | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -like $file}
```

when I compare `$file` which is the found LastWriteTime, and `$myfiles` which should contain all files with the same LastWriteTime, `$myfiles` always includes only one file - this is because the seconds are different for each object:

```
PS C:\xy> $file

Montag, 21. November 2016 13:10:08
```

*How can I find the files I need by comparing their lastwritetime properties?*

Comment: you either have a typo or your script won't work. your scripts says `$file =`, but it should be `$files =`, also second line starts with `files` instead of `$files`

Comment: @4c74356b41 `$file` should contain the LastWriteTime of the found object, while `$files` should get created right after the gci Call (OutVariable)

Comment: oh, it should be `-OutVariable files`, no `$`, also what does this achieve: `% { $_.LastWriteTime }`

Comment: @4c74356b41 thanks ;-) - I'll update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `$myfiles` always includes only one file - this is because the seconds
>   are different for each object:

Then compare only the parts of the timestamp that you're interested in - in this example we compare down to the minute:

```
$Timestamp = $file.ToString('yyyyMMddHHmm')

$myfiles = $files | ? {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyyMMddHHmm') -eq $file}
```

Comment: sometimes, I should think a bit more and get the answer myself - just like in this case. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonS sometimes additional eyes help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to just compare Year, Month, Day, Hour and Minute

```
$myfiles = $files | ? {$_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq $file.Year `
                     -and $_.LastWriteTime.Month -eq $file.Month `
                     -and $_.LastWriteTime.Day -eq $file.Day `
                     -and $_.LastWriteTime.Hour -eq $file.Hour `
                     -and $_.LastWriteTime.Minute -eq $file.Minute }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want time only and not date, so, there is a FileInfo Method that I would utilize to make the comparison easier.

Grab the time you're after:

```
$time = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Filter "*.txt" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).LastWriteTime.ToShortTimeString()
```

Then, grab the files that match:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Filter "*.txt" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.ToShortTimeString() -eq $time }
```

Answer (score -1):

Couple of ideas to possibly speed this up at least a bit.
Not sure how much they will achieve, thou.
And this is not tested, so might contain errors ;)

```
$file = ((gci C:\temp -OutVariable files).LastWriteTime | sort -Descending)[0]

$myfiles = $files.Where{$_.LastWriteTime -match $file}
```

Comment: not much of a difference, `gci` takes 99% of the time, and that won't be any different by eliminating Pipelines - but thanks ;-)